# How does a soul travel to a clone as per the spell Clone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

So the spell *Clone* states:

> At any time after the clone matures, if the original creature dies, its soul transfers to the clone, provided that the soul is free and willing to return.

Does the soul teleport to the cloned body or does it come out of the carcass and travel there? And if so how long does it take?
Also how far can the soul travel? Can it travel indefinitely? Can it travel across planes? Can it enter through Demi-planes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The spell places no restrictions on the travel of the soul. However,

> ... its soul transfers

and

> ... The original creature's physical remains ... **become** inert...

(*Emphasis mine*)

Which suggests that the intention here was that the 'transfer' is instantaneous. Other spells and effects always provide explicitly specific restrictions to their consequences. Since there are none here, it is safe to assume that none exist. Therefore, the clone becomes animate the very instant the creature dies.